# In A-Frame, what tools are used by the two file

Tags: aframe

In A-Frame, The use of  will be used to load these two files.
But some text shows a question mark.
I want to generate these two files.
How are these two files generated? What tools are used?

https://cdn.aframe.io/fonts/Roboto-msdf.json

https://cdn.aframe.io/fonts/Roboto-msdf.png

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be searching for how to create signed distance field fonts. Here are a few great resources for this:

- https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/2017/within
- https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/text.html#generating-sdf-fonts
- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts

Comment: Thank you.I used a-frame + three.js to achieve the Chinese display.

Comment: but typeface.json file is too big.